# Default properties for controls in BIDS 2005 (Report Designer) - Custom Controls

Tags: c#, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, reportingservices-2005

I'm new to BIDS.  In Business Intelligence Developer Studio 2005 in the Report designer, the default toolbox has Report Items displayed.  My end goal is simply to default the properties of the controls in that toolbox.  For example, the Textbox control should be defaulted to a specific font and background color.  How can I accomplish this?

I thought this would be a simple matter of inheriting from the windows form textbox control and adding my new 'MyTextBox' control to the toolbar.  I was able to add it successfully, but it's disabled and can't be dragged onto the report.  I saw the Custom Report Item sample [here](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005!Custom%20Report%20Item%20Sample&referringTitle=Home) but since I'm just looking to extend current functionality (or really just set default property values), hoped that it was overkill.